# Xargs rm doesn't work when running it in a script as part of a core_pattern

Tags: linux, shell-script, linux-kernel, core-dump

I am trying to run a cleanup script that gets invoked on every core dump.
I first wrote the contents of the core file to another file, and after then I tried to do a cleanup on the oldest ten files.

However, the `xargs rm` doesn't work when the script gets invoked via a core_dump. When I run the script by itself, the rm works.

/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern:

```
|core_cleanup.sh /tmp/cores/core.%t
```

cleanup.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh 
cat > "$1"
ls -tr /tmp/cores/ | head -10 | xargs rm
```

If I instead do the below to delete files, it works. But I need to delete only the oldest x files.

```
#!/bin/sh 
cat > "$1"
rm /tmp/cores
```

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: Redirect stderr and stdout to a file in `/tmp` to see the error message. Find out the user that runs the script and whether restrictions from SELinux apply.

Comment: Does the `cat` redirection work? (Is the script being invoked?)

Comment: @JeffSchaller the script is being invoked and the cat redirection works. But xargs doesn't.
When I modified the statement below cat to just do an rm /tmp/cores/, it also works.
Seems to be an issue with xargs. Is there an alternative I should try?

Comment: Ralf has a good point about SELinux possibly preventing the removal; is `sestatus` reporting "enforcing" mode, and if so, what's the context in `ls -Z /tmp/cores`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller sestatus shows disabled.

Answer (score 2):

`ls -tr /tmp/cores` doesn't list the full paths of the files, but just their basenames.

Try `ls -tr /tmp/cores/* | ...` instead.

But you don't need all that -- since all file names are of the form `core.%t` (`%t` = unix time of dump), you can simply rely on glob to sort them. Also, it doesn't make sense to remove 10 files after you're adding just one -- after a number of steps, you will end up with no files in the directory.

```
#! /bin/sh
cat > "$1"
# remove the oldest file if there are more than 100 
cleanup(){ test "$#" -gt 100 && rm "$1" }
cleanup /tmp/cores/*
```

Comment: well-spotted with the base names and the %t glob-sorting! I might suggest testing for more than 2 instead of 10, as that seems to be the requirement.

Comment: @mosvy 
what if the core patterns are of the form: core.%e.%s.%t?

Comment: @JeffSchaller ^

Comment: @Mozbi I think it’d be fair to open a new question focused on removing the X oldest files based on that (different) core pattern. Let mosvy Answer this question as asked.

Comment: (Questions are free!)

Comment: @Mozbi you change them to `core.%t.%s.%e` -- or even better, `core.%t.%p.%s.%e` (include the pid too, since a program may crash more than once per second).

Comment: If there's anything wrong with my answer please comment on it; specifically, '%t' will be *sorted the same* numerically and lexicographically (as done by glob) for all years in the range 2002-2285 -- so yes, that will fail if there are coredumps older or newer that in the directory ;-)